# Authorized ad account IDs in Facebook developers app: "Exceeded the number of permitted ad accounts."

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-webview, google-developers-console

In my Facebook developers account, to which the application is linked and Google Play store is added, under "Setting -> Advanced" in the "Advertising Accounts -> Authorized ad account IDs" I add a list of ad accounts and encounter this error (Exceeded the number of permitted ad accounts.), when authorizing more than 100 ad accounts.
Please advise how to increase this limit, or bypass it? Since we can not add all of our advertising accounts on one application.
http://joxi.ru/Vm6Yn0Ph37qdlr